# Hidden dots in the center

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What do we do with the hidden dots?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What do we do with the hidden dots?

> We **connect** them, of course.

The image ...

> ... shows nine discs in seven boxes. Each disc is subdivided into eight sectors. The sectors are either white or filled with a colour. That colour is usually grey, but there is exactly one green and one red sector in each disc. (Well, there is one sector that is both green and red in the second disc. Let's assume that the green and red sectors happen to coincide here.)

The hidden dots ...

> ... are in the centre, the title tells us. The centre could be either the centroid of each sector or the centre of the arc segments; it doesn't matter. If we connect the centres of all filled sectors, starting with the green sector and ending with the red sector (or vice versa; again, it doesn not matter), we get letters:
>
>  [image: letters from circles; they spell CONNECT]
>
>  Here, I've painted the lines from the second disc in the two boxes with two discs each on top of the first one. Their start and end sectors are filled with lighter shades of green and red.

So, in order to find the answer, ...

> ... we had to know what the answer was. But "connect the dots" is a common thing to do. In fact, the two top entries in the "related questions" list in the side bar literally had "connect the dots" in them.
>
>  And the first and sixth discs as well as the third and fourth discs have the same pattern, which suggests that they represent the same thing and that thing might well be a letter. The word "connect" fits the pattern 1233415 of the discs.

Comment: We sure do, well done!